# What is the purpose of passing a pointer to void* to pthread_join?

Tags: c, pthreads

```
pthread_t single_thread ;
pthread_create (&single_thread , NULL , &mywriter , 0) ;
void * ignore ;
pthread_join (single_thread , &ignore) ;
```

I have this code above, what is the purpose of defining void* ignore and do join of it?
I get a segmentation fault while using it.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense.  Just pass NULL as the second param rather than an uninitialized pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point of the second argument is to get the returning argument from the thread.

Something like an exit code. But since this could also be the address of an object you are returning it is a `void**` so you can modify the `void*`. If you look at the signature it is actually a `void**` that the function expects and you are passing to it.

If you don't need it, as i think is your case. Just pass `null`

> On return from a successful pthread_join() call with a non-NULL value_ptr argument, the value passed to pthread_exit() by the terminating thread is made available in the location referenced by value_ptr.

Man: [pthread_join](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/pthread_join.html)

Answer (score 1):

well the purpose of pthread_join is to "join the created thread" into the caller thread...
this makes sure that your thread does get to run before the process falls off the closing brace in main.....

eg:

```
//code
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
void *func(void *arg)
{
printf ("inside the thread %d\n",pthread_self());
return NULL;
}

int main (void)
{
pthread_t tid;

pthread_create (&tid,NULLm func,NULL);

pthread_join (tid,NULL);

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The main purpose of `pthread_join` is to **synchronize** the calling thread with the called thread. The calling thread is suspended until the called thread exits.

For example, you call `pthread_create` from your main function and create your thread. If you dont wait for the thread to exit, your main function/process exits, thereby killing the created thread too along with it irrespective of whether its done with its job or not.

Also as noted in comments, you can just pass a `NULL` as the second paramter to `pthread_join`. Using an uninitialized pointer will generally result in segmentation fault. Also, I am curious, how were you able to use (dereference) `ignore` which is a `void` pointer? May be you casted?